# What is the relationship name of my (brother/sister)-in-law's (brother/sister) to me?

Tags: kinship-terminology, non-blood-relative

For example:

- I have a sister named Charlotte
- Martin has a brother named William
- Charlotte is married to Martin

Martin is my brother-in-law, but what is William to me?

*I originally posted [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115018/what-is-the-relationship-name-of-my-brother-sister-in-laws-brother-sister-t) on English.StackExchange. A commenter referred me to ask it on this stack.*

Comment: It was my understanding (although not verified) that the term brother/sister/father/mother-in-law was originally because the families had both recognised that - through marriage  - they had become family in the eyes of the law. So I guess technically it would be brother-in-law. Although this isn't commonly used in everyday English language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no common word (though see below) for this relationship in English, but there is one in Spanish: *concuñado/a*. So William is your concuñado. This word is used a lot at some of our family gatherings.

Note that cuñado/a is Spanish for brother/sister-in-law.

However the terms *co-brother-in-law* and *co-sister-in-law* are sometimes used for this in English, but they are generally used when translating to English from a language that has a specific word for the relationship.

Answer (score 4):

Well there isn't a special name for this - he is just your brother-in-law's brother.

Comment: Or your sister's brother-in-law. Choose whichever seems more obvious. Lots of "relationships" don't have names in English (but might have in other languages).